# Suggestions on generating abstract little images like StackOverflow 'flair' image

Tags: image-processing, geometry, thumbnails, image-generation

I'm creating a webapp that has various unrelated data types (House, Contact, Article, Recipe, Fact -etc). I am giving each one a 'thumbnail' automaticaly. (User can then manually upload there own image).

Currently, I'm grabbing an image from Flikr, crop or strech to 80x80 & adding a mosaic filter at 10 pixels. The result is a nice little abstract thumbnail for each peice of data. (This lets me user 'CoverFlows, Carusel etc - for a more visual experience).

**I'd now like to collect some other suggestions on 'image generation'.**

I'd love to know how StackOverflow creates those nice little patterns for each user. (Geometric pattern generator? Any open Api?) [So much nicer than the old grey silouette!

All suggestions welcomed!
Thanks

Comment: Interesting algorithm - the pattern generating is based on a traditional 9 block quilting process. Classic!

http://www.levitated.net/daily/lev9block.html

Answer (score 2):

That's actually not Stack Overflow but Gravatar creating those images. They are [Identicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) created from a hash of the user's email address. The linked Wikipedia article also lists several implementations.

There are also some Stack Overflow questions on that topic:

- [What is the algorithm used to generate those little Gravatar identicon images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images)
- [How Do I Generate Random Identicons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186050/how-do-i-generate-random-identicons)

Comment: Thanks - Wikipedia article very interesting. We're going to setup a Web Service / REST to sent back a random identicon. We'll post when complete. - thx